# If condition order in list comprehension

Tags: python

Suppose the below variables:

```
xs = [1,2]
ys = ['a','b']
```

I also have 2 for loops and an if condition like below:

```
zs = []   
for x in xs:
    for y in ys:
        if x == 2:
            zs.append(x * y) 
        else:
            zs.append(y * 3)
```

and the output is like below:

['aaa', 'bbb', 'aa', 'bb']

how can I achieve this with list comprehension?
I have tried the below code, which is an invalid syntax:

```
zs = [(x * y) for x in xs for y in ys if x == 2 else y * 3]
```

As far as I know, in list comprehension, the first for corresponds to outer loop and the second loop corresponds to inner loop.

If I provide the "If condition" before the "for loop", it means that the code first checks the condition and then the for loops and if I provide the "for loops" first and then the "If condition", it means that first the for loops run and within the inner for loop, the "If condition" validates. Is that right?

I hope I could articulate my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following list comprehension:

```
zs = [(x * y) if x == 2 else (y * 3) for x in xs for y in ys]
```

Result:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'aa', 'bb']
```

Comment: thanks. however I could not find the answer regarding the order of using "If condition" and "For loops" in list comprehension. I mean does writing the "IF condition" before the "For" mean that the codes first validates the condition and then run the loops and vice versa?

Comment: The way the list comprehension is written means that the "for" loop is executed and then the "if condition" is validated.